Execute method only once based on Compose State update and Orientation Change
I'm using Accompanist to get permission in my Compose app. When permission is granted, I want to call a method in my ViewModel that makes a network request. I want this method to invoke only once after permission is granted.
This is what I have so far:
val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
)
LaunchedEffect(cameraPermissionState) {
    if (cameraPermissionState.status == PermissionStatus.Granted) {
        viewModel.callServerMethod()
    }
}
Button(onClick = { cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }) {
    Text("Get permission")
}

The issue here is that on config change (eg device rotation etc.) the composable is recreated, which causes the LaunchedEffect and thus callServerMethod to invoke again.
Is there any way to execute the ViewModel call only the first time? I suppose my use-case is more like an event rather than a state.

You can restrict Activity Recreation for a certain number of scenarios as mentioned here
So I would actually go and do this in the AndroidManifest.xml file, for the Activity in which your above composable resides
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

Apart from that, you can keep your entire code the same

Composable will always recompose on config changes. Wont it affect the logic?

Composable will always recompose on config changes -> Yes it will recompose because the host activity recomposes. If you prevent the host activity from recomposing, this will not happen, and that is exactly what I've suggested

Since you use ViewModel you can use a Boolean flag which you can set to opposite after you get response next time lambda of LaunchedEffect invoked with an if check you can prevent same function being called. You can also check if your model is null or empty depending on your design. Important point is having an if check to not call same function again that resided in a container such as ViewModel that survives configuration changes.
Both alternatives above pseudo code, you can modify it as required
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
   private var isResponseFetched = false

    fun getSomeModelFromServer() {
        if(isResponseFetched.not()) {
             api.fetchModel()
        }
    }
}

or like this
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var isResponseFetched = false

    fun getSomeModelFromServer() {
         api.fetchModel()
         isResponseFetched = true
    }
}

Inside your Composable
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    if(viewModel.isResponseFetched.not()) {
         viewModel.getSomeModelFromServer()
    }
}

Since configuration change triggers recomposition you don't need to use MutableState nor any key with LaunchedEffect. In cases where you need recomposition to be triggered you should use MutableState, and set value as key of LaunchedEffect to reset it when value changes.
